# Maven - How to build a dependency project

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I have a mutli-module project.

- Parent -> has submodules ProjectA and ProjectB
- Project A depends on ProjectB's target files generated during a build
- Project A has a dependency defined for ProjectB

How do I get ProjectB to build when I build ProjectA (I need to make sure ProjectB builds properly and creates its Jar)?

When I build the Parent project all the Project builds are executed properly, but I want to all ProjectA to be built separately (which builds its dependency ProjectB) as well.

Comment: If you have defined the dependency of Project B to Project A correctly it should work without any problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid you cannot do that. You already have an aggregator project, parent, that builds ProjectA and ProjectB. You cannot trigger projectB to be build only when invoking mvn on projectA. If you could, building your aggregator would build B, then B again, then A.

Comment: Thanks - that's what I was afraid of. I seems like I could achieve this my making Proj B a submodule of Proj A, but I dont want to do that. I suppose Building the parent will have to suffice - thanks!